# Problem with finding a subfolder in OneDrive

Tags: rest, http, microsoft-graph-api, postman, onedrive

I would like to use the Microsoft APi point

```
/drives/{id}/root/subfolder
```

when I address it with Postman(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{MyUserId}/root/NameOfMyFolder`) I get a 404 and an Item not found message.

BTW: The folder NameOfMyFolder does exists ;-)

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

What am I doing wrong ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl2av.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the image contains url in postman?

Comment: Has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
GET .../{driveID}/root:/foldername
```

Note the `:` in front of `root`. Reference page on Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: But what's with /drives/{id}/root/subfolder ? This is supported by the MS Graph webhooks.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

Comment: @ChsharpNewbie you can refer to the drive itself in a variety of ways, see the link in the answer

Comment: Runs great with Postman, but in with MS Graph Webhook does not work.